# WPF absolute positioning in InkCanvas

Tags: wpf, css-position, inkcanvas

I'm trying to position a rectangle in an `InkCanvas`. I am using the following method. Unfortunately when I add the rectangle it gets displayed at `(0,0)`. Although when I query to see the whether the left property is `0` I get a non zero values. Does anyone know why this might be?

Cheers,

Nilu

```
InkCanvas _parent = new InkCanvas();
private void AddDisplayRect(Color annoColour, Rect bounds)
    {
        Rectangle displayRect = new Rectangle();
        Canvas.SetTop(displayRect, bounds.Y);
        Canvas.SetLeft(displayRect, bounds.X);

        // check to see if the property is set
        Trace.WriteLine(Canvas.GetLeft(displayRect));
        displayRect.Width = bounds.Width;
        displayRect.Height = bounds.Height;
        displayRect.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(annoColour);
        displayRect.StrokeThickness = 1;

        _parent.Children.Add(displayRect);            
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally able to figure out. I feel kinda stupid too. Instead of `Canvas.SetTop()` need to use `InkCanvas.SetTop`.